# Remote connection to MySQL SERVER Windows

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I am trying to remote connect do a MySQL server. I have already given the user permitions from any IP, and tried to change the address-bind to 0.0.0.0

Still I can´t connect. Every time I try I recive the follow error " Failed to connect at ***x.x.x.x*** with user ***XXXX***
Cant connect to MySQL Server on ***x.x.x.x*** (10060)."

Does anyone have any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: are you using mysql workbench

Comment: yes @E-housmaMardini